# What is the cleanest way to access a logged in Firebase user across your Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using firebase in my flutter app and accessing the logged in user would be done something like this -

```
  Future<FirebaseUser> getLoggedInUser() async {
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  }
```

I use BLOC and was thinking of adding this to my `AuthenticationBloc` class. Since this BLOC is injected early, I should be able to access this from anywhere in the app -

```
AuthenticationBloc authBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context);
FirebaseUser user = await authBloc.getLoggedInUser()
```

But this leads to a few problems like accessing this in a StreamBuilder becomes an issue because of the need of using await which means I would need to make the StreamBuilder async (not sure how).

What would be the best/cleanest way of accessing the user object `FirebaseUser user` from anywhere in the app ?

Thanks !

**Edit 1 :**

So one way to do this would be to use a stateful widget every time I want the current user

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  FirebaseUser user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _updateCurrentUser();
  }

  void _updateCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser currUser = await Firebase.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      user = currUser;
    });
  }
```

But using a stateful widget every time I want the currUser seems weird. Is there a better way out ?

Comment: Are you using a state management solution where you can store the `FirebaseUser`. Very little information is saved on that object and it's unlikely to change often, why do you need to keep fetching it from `Firebase`?

Comment: Well, I would just want to rely on Firebase for all the auth. I could cache it, but wasn't sure if thats a good idea because Firebase maintains all the oauth expiration.  But even if I cache it, what would be returned would still be a Future<Firebaseuser> object. There is still the issue with using this in a Streambuilder right ? Any suggestions on how that could be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the user by using stream such as

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream:FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder:(context,snapshot){
     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        final user = snapshot.data;
         return Text("User Id:${user.uid}");
        }else{
         return Center(
            child:CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
      }
  }

);
```

Comment: Well, you need access to the currUser while working with other firebase queries. So in this case ill have to nest streams or use something like StreamZip. Seems too much, no ?

Comment: you can pass the user through provider return Provider<FirebaseUser>.value(
              value: user,
              child:OtherWidget()
            );